Values From appsettings File Not Picked Up When .net 8.0 Executable Invoked via Azure Pipeline
I have a .net 8.0 Console application deployed to a server which when invoked directly on the server works as expected, but when invoked via a PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3 Azure 'Classic' Pipeline task the appsettings.json file seems to not be loaded.
The first time the code attempts to get a value from the JSON settings file, it returns null.
The application works locally, it works on the remote server when invoked directly by double clicking on the executable, but is not picking up the appsettings.json configuration settings when invoked via the PowerShell script via the Azure pipeline on the target server.
Note, it also works when running the PowerShell script manualy on the server as well.
YAML for the 'Classic' Pipeline task:
steps:
- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
displayName: 'Run PowerShell on Target Machines'
inputs:
  Machines: 127.0.0.1
  UserName: 'Domain\admin-geezer'
  UserPassword: '$(UserPassword)'
  ScriptType: FilePath
  ScriptPath: 'C:\Program Files\App-Location\App.ps1'

Powershell Script (on the server):
& "dotnet" "C:\Program Files\App-Location\App.exe"

The code in the Program.cs file that is returning null:
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
...
var connectionString = builder.Configuration["ServiceBus:ConnectionString"];

The code fails as follows:

Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Have you already tried to set the Environment variables ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT or DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT to your staging environment like „Development“ or „Production“? Usually these settings are missing.

If you directly manually run the PowerShell command lines on the server machine, does the same error occur?

@decius I'm not sure the Environment variables are the issue as there is only one appsettings file and it all works fine when invoked manually.

@BrightRan-MSFT, running directly works fine, no errors. Via the PowerShell script or when double clicking the .exe.

@BillyRayValentine, How about manually running connect from the agent machine to the remote machine to run the PowerShell script via WinRM?

@BillyRayValentine, You can try to connect from the agent machine to the remote machine like as below.
$computerName = "{computerName}"
$Username = "{Username}"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "{Password}" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$password)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName  -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command "path/to/script.ps1"}

@BillyRayValentine, The computerName can be either the FQDN or IP address of the remote machine. The "path/to/script.ps1" is the absolute path of the PowerShell script on the remote machine.

By default, when building the .NET 8.0 Console application, it also will generate a framework-dependent application DLL (appName.dll) together with the application EXE (appName.exe). To use the dotnet command to run the application, you can call the DLL file like as below.
dotnet path/to/appName.dll

To call the EXE file, you can try to use the command 'start' or PowerShell cmdlet 'Start-Process'.
start path/to/appName.exe

or
Start-Process -FilePath "path/to/appName.exe"



Thanks for the input but I've tried these options before. Using Start-Process does not seem to actually invoke the executable, even though the Pipeline succeeds.

@BillyRayValentine, Try to manually run connect from the agent machine to the remote machine to run the PowerShell script via WinRM.
